# Apply magento shoping cart rule to 4 different items only

Tags: php, magento

I have a store where i would like to give 20% discount to some products if a specific product is added.
Example: 
I have 8 products A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H
and users selects all the products I only want to give discount on A,B,D,E.

How this can be done using shopping cart rule magento?

Answer (score 1):

With Shopping cart price rules you can apply discount for specific products using product's SKU

[This link will help (section X% off specific products)](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/3_-_store_setup_and_management/shopping-cart-price-rule-recipes)